# Можно ли полностью скрыть айпи адрес?

Tags: ip

В рамках тестирования нужно имитировать кейс, когда система не может определить айпи адрес пользователя, и на основании этого должна сработать определенная фича. Но пока не найшёл инфы как этого сделать.

Вариант со скрытием айпи адреса не подходит.

На этом у меня всё.

Comment: Чтобы избавиться от IP-адреса, вам необходимо полностью отказаться от протокола IP и всего работающего поверх него (TCP, UDP, HTTP) и использовать вместо него что-то другое. Например, в прошлом веке имел некоторую популярность IPX/SPX.

Comment: ip адрес есть всегда, а вот личный ли это ip пользователя, общий адрес nat или адрес прокси сервера в общем случае вы не знаете никогда. Поэтому надо начинать с того, что именно вы понимаете под терминами "ip пользователя" и "определение ip адреса"

Comment: Если только использовать прокси-сервер. А так скрыть IP пользователя не получится потому, что отвечать-то надо, а если в поле IP пользователя мусор, то ответ не дойдет. Если только у Вас связь в одну сторону, и ответов не нужно, то можно попробовать. Да и то, как на это посмотрят промежуточные роутеры...

Comment: Если для тестирования "на столе" Вам это нужно, то это наверное можно сделать. Собираете локальную сеть без роутеров, просто кабель, создаете RAW-сокет на тестирующей машине и пуляете какие хотите пакеты с каким хотите обратным адресом.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, но ведь поддерживается открытое соединение для отправки ответа. Если бы всё работало по твоему описанию, нельзя было бы передавать данные за nat.

Comment: @andreymal, а если как бы использовать http, но при этом в пакетах вместо верного ip указать нули, например? Возможно такое? И какие будут последствия?

Comment: @Qwertiy даже если никто не пошлёт такой пакет нафиг, всё равно будет IP-адрес 0.0.0.0 :)

Comment: @andreymal, ну это понятно, что он будет. Просто интересно, может ли подобное вообще работать?